# How to convert multiple photos into video using jcodec

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have three photos that are entered by the user
using a camera or gallery I have saved the photos that the user takes with this code

```
 private void openImageIntent(int type) {

    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myapp" + File.separator);

    boolean success = root.exists() || root.mkdir();

    if (success) {
        final String fName = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(root, fName));

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.Select_image));

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, type);
    } else {
        // Filesystem.
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.Select_image));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, type);
    }

}



  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Select Image from Camera Or Gallery
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    // Camera
                    isCamera = true;

                } else {
                    String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        // Gallery
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        // Camera OR Gallery
                        isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

                Uri selectedImageUri = isCamera ? outputFileUri : data.getData();

                if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                    // Start Cropping Image Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
                    String destinationFileName = "SampleCropImage_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                    Uri outputCropImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), destinationFileName));

                    UCrop uCrop = UCrop.of(selectedImageUri, outputCropImageUri);

                    uCrop.withOptions(getUCropOptions(this));

                    uCrop.start(this);

                } else
                    ShowMessage("ERORR");

            } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    // Camera
                    isCamera = true;

                } else {
                    String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        // Gallery
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        // Camera OR Gallery
                        isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

                Uri selectedImageUri = isCamera ? outputFileUri : data.getData();

                if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                    // Start Cropping Image Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
                    String destinationFileName = "SampleCropImage_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                    Uri outputCropImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), destinationFileName));

                    UCrop uCrop = UCrop.of(selectedImageUri, outputCropImageUri);

                    uCrop.withOptions(getUCropOptions(this));

                    uCrop.start(this);

                } else
                    ShowMessage("ERORR");

            } else if (requestCode == 3) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    // Camera
                    isCamera = true;

                } else {
                    String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        // Gallery
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        // Camera OR Gallery
                        isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

                Uri selectedImageUri = isCamera ? outputFileUri : data.getData();

                if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                    // Start Cropping Image Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
                    String destinationFileName = "SampleCropImage_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                    Uri outputCropImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), destinationFileName));

                    UCrop uCrop = UCrop.of(selectedImageUri, outputCropImageUri);

                    uCrop.withOptions(getUCropOptions(this));

                    uCrop.start(this);

                } else
                    ShowMessage("ERORR");

            }


            // Crop Result
            if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && type == 1) {
                Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                if (resultUri != null) {

                    byte[] imageByte = ImageUtils.compressImage(this, resultUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getBitmapFromByte(imageByte);


                    Image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else
                    ShowMessage("ERORR");


            } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && type == 2) {
                Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                if (resultUri != null) {

                    byte[] imageByte = ImageUtils.compressImage(this, resultUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getBitmapFromByte(imageByte);

                    Image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else
                    ShowMessage("ERORR");
            } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && type == 3) {
                Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                if (resultUri != null) {

                    byte[] imageByte = ImageUtils.compressImage(this, resultUri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getBitmapFromByte(imageByte);

                    Image3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else
                    ShowMessage("ERORR");
            }

        }
        if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            final Throwable cropError = UCrop.getError(data);
            if (cropError != null)
                Toast.makeText(this, cropError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                ShowMessage("Erorr");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I make these images that were entered by the user turn into a video using jcodec library ?
Please, I need a code that matches my code When I paste it works I am a beginner, I searched a lot and found many solutions but it is not at all clear to me
How do I make these images that were entered by the user turn into a video using jcodec library ?
Thanks <3.

Comment: this may help you [Jcodec Images to Video](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec#h264-video-from-png-images)

Comment: I entered this page before, but there is no complete code with examples that I could not understand